# How can I run an .exe on a server, but show output and interact client-side?

Tags: executable, client-side

I want to run an .exe (Halo to be specific) on a server and then be able to view and interact with it through a browser, similar to a remote desktop. Is this even possible? I want to do this because we have nothing left to do in the last few days of school, and we wanted to play a Halo LAN, but are not allowed to install anything on the computer or run anything off of a flash drive, thus this was an idea we came up with.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in principle it would be possible (though performance would probably be a problem), but in order to do this, you'd need at least some kind of viewer on the client. This in turn would need to be installed :-).

You could try to set up a VNC server, then use the [TightVNC java viewer](http://www.tightvnc.com/doc/java/README.txt). That would work if the school's computers have Java set up. Still, I don't believe you'd get usable performance (VNC typically gives you 1 FPS at best).

Your best option is to either play browser games, or just do something else with your time. You might even try studying something interesting :-).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like too much of a hassle. I guess I'll just continue to research how to write a linux driver :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way, and it's called [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), but you won't be running Halo with it anytime soon.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think I could use CGI without actually coding the entire Halo game, which I think would take a bit too long for too little gain ;)

Comment: @Looterguf : You could try `Quake Live` as an alternative.